# Django rest_api and React

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an am using Django and React. I have created custom user model api in Django using rest-framework, but i am confused about the whole login and signup system. Do we create login and signup modules in Django or React.
Can anyone please guide me through it, or suggest any tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You create the templates (login, signup, etc. pages) in React and connect them to DRF. There are multiple ways to perform authentication. Take a look to Authentication docs on DRF. https://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication